# How to showing HTML in Java fx?

Tags: java, html, windows, javafx, text

I am coding a Windows tchat software in JavaFx. I want to display HTML text but without showing the tags. How to do that? There are some examples:

1)
String received: `"<p>Toto tata titi</p>"`.
What I want to display: "Toto tata titi".

2. Other example:
   String received: `"<p>Test 1 <br> Test 2</p>"`.
   What I want to display:

   "Test 1 
   Test 2"

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Display it in a `WebView`.

Comment: Thank you @James_D! I will take your solution.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX offers the WebView for this case. You can simply display any HTML Page with it.

```
String received = "<p>Toto tata titi</p>"; 
WebView webView = new WebView();
```

WebEngine is a internal component of WebView which manages to load the data which should be displayed in the WebView.

```
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.loadContent(received , "text/html");
```